# How to refer my own environment variables in NDK(Android.mk)

Tags: android, android-ndk, environment-variables

I have some problem.

I have my own environment variables(ex: MY_HOME). and I want to use this in my **Android.mk**.
so I have tried to do like following,

```
MY_DIR := $(MY_HOME)
...
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(MY_DIR)/sources/test.cpp
```

but for compiling MY_DIR has no content. I mean that $(MY_DIR) returns blank("").

How to refer my own environment variables in **Android.mk**

Comment: You are doing it correctly, except that I don't understand why you assign to MY_DIR instead of using $(MY_HOME) directly. Please post your Android.mk fully, you might clearing the variables along the lines.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is a just sample code. my question is whether I can use my own environment variables like $(MY_HOME). I've tried to use $(MY_HOME) in my Android.mk but it does not work correctly.

Comment: Is it Eclipse environment variables or OS environment variables? Because I can confirm Eclipse variables do not work with NDK and OS variables work normally.

Comment: It is OS environment variables. I'm using Mac Book and I have added "export MY_HOME=/test/lib" in "~/.profile" file.